# Stuck after a cout in a while loop

Tags: c++, linux, while-loop

I am currently trying to work on how to write and read on a serial port on Linux. Yesterday my program worked with no issue but since this morning it seems stuck in a loop.

Here is the part which causes the issue:

```
void *ReadModBusRTU(void *threadarg) {
  cout << "thread lecture" << endl;
  i      = 0;
  bufptr = buffer;
  while(1) {
    cout << "enter while loop" << endl;
    if ( (nbytes = read(fd, bufptr, 1) ) > 0) {
      cout << std::hex << bufptr;
      lecture[i] = buffer[0];
      //cout << " lecture[" << i << "] : " << lecture[i] << endl;
      i++;
      // cout << "i : " << i << endl;
      cout.flush();
    } else {
      cout << "lecture du port serie..." << endl;
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Normally it should stay in the `while(1)` loop and do what it must but since this morning it is doing the cout "enter while loop" and then nothing.

Not the else, not cout "enter while loop" once again. It simply is stuck after the cout. I am kind of lost on why this is happening since it worked well yesterday. I have another pthread with a similar architecture and it is working well.

Edit code read :

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include "iostream"
#include "pthread.h"

/*
 * 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
 *
 * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
 */

using namespace std;

int open_port(void);
int rc;
volatile int i=0;
pthread_t threads[2];
char buffer[255];  /* Input buffer */
volatile char lecture[255];
char donnees[255];
char *bufptr;      /* Current char in buffer */
int  nbytes;       /* Number of bytes read */
int  tries;        /* Number of tries so far */
int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
struct termios options;

struct thread_data{
    float limite;
    int threadcible;
    int prise;
};

struct thread_data td[1];


void *ReadModBusRTU(void *threadarg){
    /* read characters into our string buffer until we get a CR or NL */
    cout<<"thread lecture"<<endl;
    i=0;
     bufptr = buffer;
     while(1){

     //if ((nbytes = read(fd, bufptr, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - bufptr - 1)) > 0)
     if ((nbytes = read(fd, bufptr, 1)) > 0)
     {
         cout<<std::hex<<bufptr;
            lecture[i]=buffer[0];
         //cout<<" lecture["<<i<<"] : "<<lecture[i]<<endl;
         i++;
         //cout<<"i : "<<i<<endl;
       cout.flush();

     }
   }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



void *TravailModBusRTU(void *threadarg){
 cout<<"thread travail"<<endl;

     while(1)
     {

   if(lecture[0]=='1' && lecture[1]=='2')
        {
        cout<<"lecture 12"<<endl;
        if((nbytes = read(fd, bufptr, 1))==0)
            {

            cout<<"lecture terminee"<<endl;
            int j=0;
            for(j=0;j<=254;j++)
                {
                donnees[j]=lecture[j];
                }
            cout<<"donnee : "<<donnees<<endl;
            //cout.flush();
            for(i=0;i<=254;i++)
                {
                lecture[i]='Z';
                }
                i=0;
            }
        }

    }
     pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(){
    //close(fd);
    open_port();


for(i=0;i<=254;i++){

    lecture[i]='Z';

}

    rc = pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, TravailModBusRTU, (void *)&td);

    if (rc){

    cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;

    exit(-1);

    }
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, ReadModBusRTU, (void *)&td);

    if (rc){

    cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;

    exit(-1);

    }



    while(1){

    }
    return 0;
}




int open_port(void)
{


  /*
   * Get the current options for the port...
   */

  tcgetattr(fd, &options);

  /*
   * Set the baud rates to 57600...
   */

  cfsetispeed(&options, B57600);
  cfsetospeed(&options, B57600);

  //No parity (8N1):
  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  //options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;
  options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

  //no hardware control flow
  //options.c_cflag &= ~CNEW_RTSCTS;

  /*
   * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
   */

  //options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

  /*
   * Set the new options for the port...
   */

  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */

  fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
   /*
    * Could not open the port.
    */

    cout<<"open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyf1 - "<<endl;
  }
  else{
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);}

  return (fd);
}
```

code write :

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include "iostream"


/*
 * 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
 *
 * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
 */


using namespace std;


int open_port(void);


int main(){
    open_port();
}


int open_port(void)
{
  char buffer[255];  /* Input buffer */
  char *bufptr;      /* Current char in buffer */
  int  nbytes;       /* Number of bytes read */
  int  tries;        /* Number of tries so far */
  int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
  struct termios options;


  /*
   * Get the current options for the port...
   */


  tcgetattr(fd, &options);


  /*
   * Set the baud rates to 57600...
   */


  cfsetispeed(&options, B57600);
  cfsetospeed(&options, B57600);


  //No parity (8N1):
  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  //options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;


  //no hardware control flow
  //options.c_cflag &= ~CNEW_RTSCTS;


  /*
   * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
   */


  options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);


  /*
   * Set the new options for the port...
   */


  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);


  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */


  fd = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
   /*
    * Could not open the port.
    */


    cout<<"open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS1 - "<<endl;
  }
  else{
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);}

  int n;

  char test[]="123";

  n=write(fd,test,sizeof(test));


  return (fd);
}
```

Comment: What are `fd` and `buffer`?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall fd is the file descriptor for the port and buffer is a char array where i get what i am reading. I used this page to base my code on : http://mirror.datenwolf.net/serial/

Comment: It loos like read() blocks while waiting for input.

Comment: @PeterG. This is what i am thinking too but i can't seems to find a reason why since it worked before when no character was received . I am currently searching a way to put a timeout on it.

Comment: @Wowy Have you checked whether i.e. your firewall allows reading from the port? Given that yesterday it worked I would go with an idea that the port is somehow blocked by your OS or it's not working properly. Try to read from it using other application like `putty` to be sure it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: @PiotrSliwa I disabled the firewall and gave o+rw permission to the serial port to be sure. Still stuck on read().

Comment: @Wowy Does it work properly with a third-party application (like `putty`)?

Comment: What is `lecture`?  And how do you ensure that `lecture[i]` exists?  How do you stop that loop from `i` going out of bounds of `lecture`, assuming lecture is an array-type (not a `std::map` or something similar)?

Comment: Do you use an usb adapter? Maybe the port has changed after you it was detached and reattached it?

Comment: @PiotrSliwa when checking the port /dev/ttyS0 with putting and sending data to it via my other device i see that at least i am receiving things everytime i send a message.

Comment: @SimonKraemer No it is a serial to serial connection, i tested each pin of the cable this morning in case there was a defaut. The cable is intact.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie lecture is a volatile char array which is filled with before launching the threads. So it exist. When a complete message is read another thread put i=0.

Comment: @Wowy You may have filled that array in, but your loop is `while(1)` and no code is done to ensure that `i` does not go out of bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added a if(i<254) (my char array max position) with an else setting i to 0. Now i should never go out of bounds.

Comment: More specific: what is the value of `fd`? Is it actually the file you think it is? It doesn't happen to be zero? That would mean that it's trying to read standard input. Otherwise it could be some other special file.

Comment: @skyking fd is and int, fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); is how i open my port. I know it is open because i check if fd == -1 and it is not. now for no reason i can read something but it is gibberish...

Comment: @Wowy That it should not be open is not my concern - `read` returns immediately in that case. My concern is that the file descriptor does not refer to the file you think it does or that the operating mode is note what you think it is. That you get gibberish is an indication that you don't run the source you've posted - you should make all efforts to post the actual code you're running.

Comment: @skyking I updated my post with the entire code of my reading and writing serial program right now i you want to take a look.

Comment: Do you see the output: `lecture 12` ?

Answer (score 0):

In `open_port` it looks like you clear the `O_NDELAY`/`O_NONBLOCK` flag if open succeeds. So that would mean that the `fd` is in blocking mode when you execute `ReadModBusRTU`.

I'd guess that `dev/ttyS0` is a special file where data might not be immediately available...